# C# Code First SaveChanges does not update navigational properties/foreign key values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have this weird issue wherein when I add new values to database. suppose to be I expected also that the navigational properties will have data after `UnitOfWork.SaveChanges()`.

Heres my model:

```
    [Column("Client_ID"), Key]
    public int ClientID{ get; set; }

    [Column("Employee_ID"), Required]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public virtual Employee201 Employee { get; set; }
```

On save changes only the ClientID updated the values not the Employee with foreign key. Am I lacking something here?

**Repository method**

```
    public Client Create(Client  client )
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            GetDbSet<Client  >().Add(client );
            UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
        return client ;
    }
```

**Update**

Now i found the issue. when im adding new data im using new Client() this result to entity type only and not proxy type. Is there a way to convert this when im using new Client() that it should always be proxy type?

Comment: How you created `client`?

Answer (score 0):

What is Employee201 ?

I always write this way
And it works.

(Clients is your dbset. 
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet< Client> Clients { get; set; })

UnitOfWork = new DataBaseContext();

UnitOfWork.Clients.Add(client);

UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();